# Any way to preserve portable hotspot configuration (SSID, key)?

Tags: settings, wifi-hotspot, wifi-password

How can I preserve my initial portable hotspot configuration (mainly current SSID, encryption) settings on my device. I noticed when I use 3rd-party applications (such as WiFi transfer, Mi Drop etc) my hotspot configuration gets messed up and worse deletes the previous encryption, sometimes I only find out later that situation.

So in case of unattended session, I would love to preserve my initial config, to prevent unauthorised access to portable hotspot, which could incur significant data charges. Is there a way to achieve that [Running Android 7.0, Miui 11]

I had [automation](/questions/tagged/automation) in mind to restore back to original setting, (but can't figure out full workaround) where *the trigger type is WIFi tethering state → Enabling(but the limitation here I can't put the desired config rather its just an on switch AFAIK but I may be wrong)*

[image]

Comment: Have you tried restoring the backup of /data/misc/wifi/softap.conf and rebooting the device?

Comment: No not yet,will definitely try that